# Local Admin to retrieve other logon process MainWindowTitle

Tags: c#

I have a Win2012 server, 10 non-admin-account logonIDs interactively log on into it to run some automated app, these apps sometime will cause exception and pop a msgbox titled "AutoApp.exe - Application Error" with **OK** button. So we have to logon with each 10 logonID to manually click on it to release resources.

I'm writing a monitoring C# console program, to fetch each process then their `MainWindowTitle`, simulate a key stroke of  to let it go. This monitoring program is run with Admin right.

```
    IntPtr hwnd;
    Process[] pp = Process.GetProcesses();
    try
    {
        foreach (Process p in pp)
        {
            ...
            title = p.MainWindowTitle;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            if (title.Equals(...) )
            {
                hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
                SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
                // simulate keystroke below...
            }
```

Test shows it's able to display all local process's window title, not other logon's. I guess this is reasonable for security reason. But is there any way to do that and how?

Comment: You are attacking this issue from the wrong direction. The problem is with the automated app. Any application used as part of an automated process should not be displaying errors to the interactive user (which is what is causing your issue). They should be self-recovering. Catch the exception, log it, notify tech support, continue on or exit gracefully.

Comment: Agree, but they are 3rd-party vendor app, not home-grown.

Comment: Then I think you're kind of stuck. The entire Windows security subsystem is written expressly to prevent you (or a virus) from doing what you are attempting to do.

Comment: If you want to go assembler, you may be able to write something to run in ring 0 that should be able to access the execution space of other applications.

Comment: @Kevin what if the process under diff user acct is actually started within Task Scheduler? Same privacy and security?

Comment: Yes, the security is about who "owns" the applications memory/execution space, not how or from where it was started.